# C# COM DLL: do I use Regasm, or Regsvr32?

Tags: com, interop, x86, 64-bit, activex

I am building a C# ActiveX DLL... do I use REGASM or REGSVR32 to register it?

How do I register the 64-bit interface vs the 32-bit interface?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to use [`regasm.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to register both the 32 bit and 64 bit interfaces I believe you need to run each of the `regasm.exe`'s in:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
```

and

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
```

So... in your case you need to run the `regasm.exe` in the `Framework64\v2.0.50727` folder.

Here's an example we use to register a COM interop DLL for one of our legacy ASP apps:

```
regasm.exe Hosting.DeviceManager.Power.dll /register /codebase /tlb
```

Answer (score 2):

If the DLL is build in format of "Any CPU", no matter if you choose regasm in

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
```

or

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
```

DLL would be registered as 32-bit.

Comment: From what I read elsewhere, I thought Framework64\...\regasm will register 64 bit.