# Use .NET Framework Libraries in 64bit assembly referenced from VBA7 in Excel

Tags: interop, 64-bit, office-addins, regasm, typelib

I have a library written in C# that uses standard .NET framework libraries (System, System.Windows.Forms). 
This library is COMVisible as well as its classes, I just have two classes:
- TestClass (a class with one method)
- TestForm (an empty form)

I registered the assembly as suggested here: [C# COM DLL: do I use Regasm, or Regsvr32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372140/c-sharp-com-dll-do-i-use-regasm-or-regsvr32)

Then I went to my Excel Add-In and added a reference to the generated .TLB file.

I am able to create an instance of my "TestClass" and invoke its method without any problem, but when I try to create an instance of my "TestForm" it shows me this error:

```
Run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)':

Automation error
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

According to the issues I saw when trying to get the class working, the problem is that one of the dependencies (I'm guessing System.Windows.Forms) is not being found by Excel.

How do I open a Form written in .NET from my 64bit Office add-in?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty standard DLL Hell problem.  Fuslogvw.exe tells you about managed assembly resolution problems.  SysInternals' ProcMon gives you *everything*.  Some digging required.

Answer (score 1):

Below example may helps u how VBA7 code works in 64bit Office.

Adding into the 64Bit Office Addins may not be a problem, but when you try to use them in the VBA7,u will definetly experiance a problem.

Testing if weither using the 64-bit version(VBA7) of Office 2010:

```
#If Win64(VBA7) Then
   Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount64 Lib "kernel32" () As LongLong
#Else(VBA)
   Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
#End If
```

If i am wrong reach me with the solution @kirantej@gmail.com
Hence, i am working on the same task too...:-P